# The development server returned response error code:500

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native

When I use "amplify push" and then my server got crashed and give me an error that says "The development server returned response error code:500" and something like duplicate files.
I also added "rn-cli.config.js" in the root folder after that same error I find. Please help me out! I am stuck from morning and I am not able to find a solution. I am using Expo.[image]